# Slider with bullets example code JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a slider with JQuery.This slider must meet the following conditions

1. Scroll automatically
2. Have scrolling arrows
3. And have content that is scrolling

Can you show me an example?
Where can I find a simple example?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are glad to help but: we won't write code on your behalf and we won't do any google search for you. So why don't you show what have you done so far and ask us for any issue? For example show us the slider you have found and then we can help you to find the way to customize to your need

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

You can find simple examples on the above page.